# Creating a UI with box shadow in react native

Tags: react-native, box-shadow

I am trying to create a UI in react native, the UI contains a box with outer shadow. using the image I have done that, but is there any proper way to do that?

[image: Attaching the image]

Answer (score 149):

You will have to use different style props for iOS and Android.

**Android**

It's very simple for android, just use the `elevation` style prop (See [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#elevation-android)) . An example:

```
boxWithShadow: {
    elevation: 5
}
```

**iOS**

In iOS you have more flexibility, use the Shadow props (See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props)). An example:

```
boxWithShadow: {
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 1,  
}
```

**Summary**

In summary, to get box shadow for both platforms, use both sets of style props:

```
boxWithShadow: {
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,  
    elevation: 5
}
```

***Attention:*** *Do not use `overflow: 'hidden';`, in `iOS` all of the shadows disappear by this property.*

Comment: Isn't there a way to customise shadow props in Android?

Comment: I don't think you can customize in Android.

Comment: and use backgroundColor: "#fff"

Comment: On iOS, this adds shadow on all the sub-elements of that box, Lol

Comment: How to set box shadow only at bottom?

Comment: and also give the box some width and height

Comment: shadowColor works on both android and iOS

Answer (score 3):

**Hey, Look it's Done Now !**

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadow: {  
      borderColor:'yourchoice', // if you need 
      borderWidth:1,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      shadowColor: 'yourchoice',
      shadowRadius: 10,
      shadowOpacity: 1,
    }
});
```

Keep in mind the shadow's props are only available for IOS.

Comment: The Shadow's props are only available for IOS.

Comment: This answer just works in `iOS` and the `overflow: 'hidden';` vanish all of the shadows, So if you wanna see the all of the shadows omit `overflow: 'hidden';`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use library "react-native-shadow-2", works for both android and iOS.
No need to write seperate chunk of code for iOS/android & has typescript support also.

Installation:

1. First install react-native-svg.
2. Then install react-native-shadow-2:
   npm i react-native-shadow-2

Structure:

```
import { Shadow } from 'react-native-shadow-2';

<Shadow>
   {/* Your component */}
</Shadow>
```

There are many props such as startColor, finalColor, radius, offset. You can use as per your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, even though a shadow effect has been applied to a component, it may not be immediately visible if the component is taking up the entire width and height of the screen. In such cases, it is recommended to adjust the component's styling by adding margin, changing the background-color, or using other visual cues to create a contrast between the component and its surroundings. This can help to highlight the shadow effect and make it more noticeable to the user.

**Style**

```jsx
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  box: {
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        shadowOffset: {
          height: 5,
          width: 5,
        },
      },
      android: {
        elevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

**Component**

```jsx
const Shadow = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.box}>{children}</View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround using a Linear Gradient for a very similar issue. I haven't found anything better anywhere on stack, so I suppose I'll add it here. It's especially nice and easy if you only want top and bottom, or side shadows.

I added a top and bottom inner box shadow to an image with full width and 140 height. You could create multiple gradients to make an outer box shadow. Don't forget about the corners. You can use the start and end props to make angled shadows / gradients, maybe that'll work for corners if you need them.

```
<ImageBackground
  source={imagePicker(this.props.title)}
  style={styles.image}
>
  <LinearGradient 
    colors={[
      'transparent',
      'transparent',
      'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
      'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
    ]}
    start={[0,0.9]}
    end={[0,1]}
    style={styles.image_shadows}
  />
  <LinearGradient 
    colors={[
      'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
      'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
      'transparent',
      'transparent'
    ]}
    start={[0,0]}
    end={[0,0.1]}
    style={styles.image_cover}
  />
</ImageBackground>



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "stretch",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop:90,
    paddingLeft:10,
    height:140,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  image_shadows: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    height: 140
  }
}
```

If you use expo you can install it with 'expo install expo-linear-gradient' [Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/). If not, I believe react-native-linear-gradient is similar [React-Native-Linear-Gradient github](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient).